# What's a better way to initialize with zero or increment for objects?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm writing analytics and I have to initialize counter counts for (keys) hours, days, weeks, years so as to get frequency of user activity. I need to create a hit count for respective time and increment accordingly. Visits are fed via a loop.
I have this working but I'm not sure if the code below is ideal to do so.

```
if(!analytics.users[message.user].counts.hourly[hour]) {
    analytics.users[message.user].counts.hourly[hour] = 0;
}
analytics.users[message.user].counts.hourly[hour] += 1;

if(!analytics.users[message.user].counts.daily[day]) {
    analytics.users[message.user].counts.daily[day] = 0;
}
analytics.users[message.user].counts.daily[day] += 1;

...
```

I've tried the x = x + 1 || 0 method but that hasn't worked.
Also, is there a way I can set up a function for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a function which take the object and the key and perfoms the check and update.

```
function increment(object, key) {
    if (!object[key]) object[key] = 0;
    ++object[key];
}
```

Call with

```
increment(analytics.users[message.user].counts.hourly, hour);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried the x = x + 1 || 0

You almost got it. It should either be:

```
x = x || 0;
x++;
```

Or

```
x = x + 1 || 1;
```

So, change your code to:

```
analytics.users[message.user].counts.hourly[hour] = 
    (analytics.users[message.user].counts.hourly[hour] + 1) || 1
```

If `analytics.users[message.user].counts.hourly[hour]` is undefined, the increment operation returns `NaN`. This is a [`falsy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value. So, it takes `1`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple increment function like the one below. It first checks for the key to be initialized and if not, it will initialize it to 0. The next line with the increment is safe to execute since the key was previously created.

```js
let message = {
  user: "user"
}

let analytics = {
  users: {
    "user": {
      counts: {
      }
    }
  }
}

function incrementAnalytics(analytics, period) {
  analytics[period] = analytics[period] || 0;
  ++analytics[period];
}

let test = analytics.users[message.user].counts;
incrementAnalytics(test, "hourly");
incrementAnalytics(test, "hourly");
incrementAnalytics(test, "daily");

console.log(test);
```

Cheers!

Comment: I'm pretty curious why did my 2 up-votes turned into 0 all of a sudden. If my code is bad, I'd like to know why next time, not to make the same mistake. Cheers!